# c# Dispose pattern

Tags: c#, idisposable

Here is a typical IDispose implementation.  What I don't understand is the destructor?
If the user of your class forgets to call Dispose, wouldn't you have a resource leak since the destructor will not call r1.Dispose()?

```
public class DisposableObject : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposed;
        private UnmanagedResource r1;

        public DisposableObject()
        {
            r1 = new UnmanagedResource();
        }

        ~DisposableObject()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {

             this.Dispose(true);
             GC.SuppressFinalize(this);       
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // clean up managed resources
                    //call dispose on your member objects
                    r1.Dispose();
                }

                // clean up unmanaged resources
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            if (this.disposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your name for `UnmanagedResource` is wrong and misleading. `r.Dispose()`  indicates that it is a managed resource.

Answer (score 2):

No - the GC will call the destructor once all references to the object are gone (this is not deterministic, however).

Answer (score 2):

If `r1` is truly a native resource (which it doesn't look like it in your example), it should not be disposed of inside the if(disposing) block but after it. Pay particular attention to:

```
if (disposing) 
{
    // free managed resources
    if (managedResource != null)
    {
        managedResource.Dispose();
        managedResource = null;
    }
}
// free native resources if there are any.
if (nativeResource != IntPtr.Zero) 
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nativeResource);
    nativeResource = IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

From [Implement IDisposable Correctly - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If `r1` is a managed resource with its own implementation of `IDisposable`, assuming it is implemented properly, any native resources will be cleaned up properly in its finalizer (which is why you don't need to worry about it in your own).

Comment: +1. Yes - the distinction is managed resources will be non-deterministically freed by run-time around the time destructor is called (or even if one does not exist), but non-managed resources must be released in destructor (which is done by Dispose(false) ).

Comment: Side note: it would have been easier to understand if MSDN use signature `Dispose(bool alsoDisposeManagedResources)` instead of `Dispose(bool disposing)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the destructor (finalizer) to call Dispose is because Garbage Collector calls it before it collects an object, guaranteeing that at least at some point the UnmanagedResource will be freed.

By using `using` and `try...finally` you can enforce the resource to be disposed as soon as they are not needed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can add a finalizer:

```
~DisposeImplementation()
{
    Dispose(false);
}
```

But it should only be used as a true last resort, not something to rely on directly.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, we have a feature called Garbage Collection. Garbage Collection finalizes all Objects that are not referenced (any more). Your Destructor / finalizer then calls Dispose().

If your user forgets to remove those references, you will end up with sort-of a leak.
But that's what `using` is for : avoid memory blockage by defining your disposables only in the scope of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern exists because the garbage collector does not guarantee the order that managed objects will be garbage collected.  So in the finalizer you are not guaranteed that the `r1` reference is still valid.

Your `r1` reference has a class name of `UnmanagedResource` but it is clearly a managaged type.  For a real unmanned resource you would only have an `IntPtr` or some other token.  To ensure that `r1` does non like it's resource it should implement the same Dispose pattern and free it's unmanaged resource outside of the `if (disposing)` check.